# Книги по asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net

Нужна книга по веб формам желательно без воды

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этой книге доходчиво описывается предмет [ASP.NET 4 Unleashed](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672331128), в оригинале использовал, так как перевода на русский нет но это не критично.